# Randomly generating numbers until they divide exactly

Tags: java

I ran into a little problem here. Basically my program below is just generating two random numbers and divide both of them.

Before that I insert a statement whereby if num1 is not divisible by num2, then num2 has to generate a number between 1 to "num1" until it is divisible.

But in the end it keeps giving me a number which is not divisible (or basically giving decimal points). I tried looking for an example in the Internet and understood so well with the modulus operator. Where did I go wrong here? I just want both numbers to be divisible that's all.

Below is my code:

```
int num1, num2, real_ans;  
Random randomGenerator = new Random();  

num1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100) + 1;  
num2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100) + 1;            

if (num1%num2!=0) {  
  do {  
    num2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(num1) + 1
  } while(num1%num2==0);  
}  
real_ans = num1 / num2;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-Generate Random Number. Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337847/re-generate-random-number-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the do/while loop to:

```
do{  
  num2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(num1) + 1
} while(num1 % num2 != 0);
```

(note the `!=`).

This loops until the numbers divide exactly.

Answer (score 0):

you are iterating with the condition that if `num1` is divisible by `num2`, keep iterating. Change the condition to `do{...}while (num1%num2 != 0);`.

You should be able to find a number that can divide `num1` with that code. The only case it still won't work is when `num1` is prime, so I suggest you check if `num1` is prime and only generate `num2`, when `num1` is not prime.

Comment: `num2` will eventually equal `1`, which will divide anything (including primes). So infinite looping is not possible.

Comment: yeah thats true, but it destroys the randomness if num2 is 1 everytime num1 is prime, since this is predictable. Just a thought.

Comment: Yeah i did make a statement for that. Just that i didn't post it here since that is not the main problem. But thanks guys!!